# Partially updating a mongo object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, javascript-objects, meteor-autoform

I have a mongo document that looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : "cfqjJW8WZprDSJEop",
    "rName" : "z1",
    "pName" : "P-4",
    "ipAddress" : "21.1.1.12",
    "misc" : {
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin",
        "creationTime" : ISODate("2016-09-15T09:43:10.953Z"),
        "updatedTime" : ISODate("2016-09-15T09:43:10.953Z")
    }
}
```

I have written code on my meteor helper such that during each update, only the `updatedBy` and `updatedTime` should be pushed on to the mongo document.

The misc object is something that is being added just before the insert / update.

I run into trouble when I try to update the record by using:

```
doc // contains the update document being generated.
misc = {};
misc.updatedBy = //some name
misc.updatedTime = new Date();

doc.misc = misc,

r.update(id,doc); // calling meteor update
```

However, when the update happens, what is happening is that the query is completely replacing the misc object within the record (that contains createdBy and creationTime) with what I've passed. I end up losing the creationTime and createdBy fields.

How do I go about updating the object partially?

Since my doc object initially does not contain the misc object, I've also tried injecting in something like :

```
doc.$set.misc.updatedBy
```

But it errors out stating that updatedBy does not exist. What's the right way to update a partial object within a document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `doc.$set.misc.updatedBy`

Try this:

```
doc = {
    "$set": {
        "misc.updatedBy": "some data"
    }
};
```

Here we are using the MongoDB [`Dot Notation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to access properties of embedded documents.

---

Example:

```
var doc = {
    "$set": {
        "misc.updatedBy": "some data",
        "misc.updatedTime": new Date(),
    }
};

r.update(id, doc);
```

Comment: While I took another look at this yesterday, I noticed that $set was setting the entire object. What I did was first get the record's object data, then pull in those object properties that was not being set, added them manually to the $set and then updated the document. Extra 5 lines of code, but does the job!

Comment: @blueren Yes it does, but that additional db find operation can be quite costly depending on the situation..

Comment: From what I read, additioanal find operation in meteor takes place within the minimongo instance that is already present in the client side. So it shouldn't be too much of a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Per default the MongoDB update command will [replace the document(s) entirely](https://specify.io/how-tos/mongodb-update-documents#ReplaceDocument). To only update a specific field and don't touch the other fields of the matching documents [use the **set operator** in the MongoDB update command](https://specify.io/how-tos/mongodb-update-documents#UpdateFildsSingleDocument).